# Using shelljs on Windows and storing the output of a process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use shelljs (https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) for a project I am working on, it works like a charm on Unix based systems but once I try to use it on Windows, I am able to launch a process but I am totally unable to get the output of that process. The documentation mentioned that any of the ways below to get output should work but none of them do on Windows, any suggestions?

```
var version = exec('node --version', {silent:true}).output;

var child = exec('some_long_running_process', {async:true});
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  /* ... do something with data ... */
});

exec('some_long_running_process', function(code, output) {
  console.log('Exit code:', code);
  console.log('Program output:', output);
});
```

Comment: Which command are you trying to run. Does it execute and exit normally.

Comment: I am trying to run "wget localhost:8080 --tries=1". There is no way for me to actually know if it is running right but if I try to execute something else (let's say startup.bat for tomcat), everything works just fine and I am able to actually run tomcat (not able to get any output though)

Comment: wget is not part of shell, in linux it is installed as a program. Install wget for windows. See http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm. Once installed add "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" to PATH system variable to use it.

Comment: It is not wget only, even when I run startup.bat or even cd or pwd or anything, I do not get the output

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
child.on("data",function(data){...}
```